# Why am I making an invalid hook call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am new to React so please be patient. Could some one tell me why I am making an invalid Hook Call? I think the issue is to do with the useState(null)or the function that it is being used in. The code below shows the whole competent  I am trying to use it in Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ScrollMenu from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
import './horizontalscroll.css';

const data = [
  {
    category: "Brands",
    items: ["Gucci", "Calvin klein", "Prada"]
  },
  {
    category: "Films",
    items: ["Inception ", "Dark Night", "Home Alone"]
  }
];


const [category, setCategory] = useState(null);
const onClick = category => {
    setCategory(category);
  };


// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({ text, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="menu-item"
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );
};

// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = (list) => list.map(el => {
  const { category } = el;

  return (
    <MenuItem
      text={category}
      key={category}
    />
  );
});


const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
    >{text}</div>
  );
};


const ArrowLeft = Arrow({ text: '<', className: 'arrow-prev' });
const ArrowRight = Arrow({ text: '>', className: 'arrow-next' });

class HorizantScroller extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: 0
  };

  onSelect = key => {
    this.setState({ selected: key });
  }


  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(list, selected);

    return (
      <div className="HorizantScroller">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          arrowLeft={ArrowLeft}
          arrowRight={ArrowRight}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
          onClick={onClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HorizantScroller;
```

Comment: please show the whole component declaration

Comment: I assume you have a function component developed and trying to use `useState` hook inside. If not, then that's the case. I suggest to read through [Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) link on React's site.

Comment: I have updated with the whole component

Comment: You're not using `category` anywhere, so even if your hook call was valid, what you're trying to do isn't evident.

Comment: hooks calls must be inside function components

Answer (score 4):

Hooks can only be used in the body of a functional component. You have these lines at the top level of your file, not in any component at all:

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState(null);
const onClick = category => {
  setCategory(category);
};
```

Based on where you use onClick, my best guess is you want this to be state of the `HorizantScroller` component, but HorizantScroller is a class component, not a function component, so you can't use hooks their either.

I'm afraid from the information provided i can't make a concrete suggestion, because it's not clear what you're trying to do. So i'd recommend deciding what component you want this to be the state of. If that component is a function component, move the code inside it. If that component is a class component, then it either needs to be turned into a function component, or it needs to use `this.state` and `this.setState` for its state management.

Answer (score 0):

First things First the main reason Hooks was released in React is to have the ability to setup a internal state in a pure function.I would suggest you to use pure functions instead of class based function if ur looking to implement state using react Hooks[react hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook)

Here is a example from the documentation form react:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Example() {
// Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

return (
  <div>
   <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
   <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
     Click me
   </button>
  </div>
 );
}
```

and To use the function based component you could do something like this

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Example from './example/example.js'
ReactDOM.render(<Example />);
```