# React Hooks - Invalid Hook Call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I am getting an error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

This is my hook  `useParking`:

```
import { Strings } from "..";
import { get } from "../HTTPProvider";
import { Lot } from ".";
import { Moment } from "moment";
import L from "leaflet";

interface ApiResponse {
  id: string;
  fields: Lot;
  createdTime: Moment | string;
}

const { apiUrl, apiKey } = Strings;
const [error, setError] = useState(false);

const getParkingLots = (setParkingLots: (l: Lot[]) => void) => {
  get<{ records: ApiResponse[] }>(`${apiUrl}Parking%20Lots`, { apiKey })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      const data: Lot[] = [];

      response.data.records.forEach((record) => {
        const lat = record.fields.latitude;
        const lon = record.fields.longitude;

        if (lat && lon) record.fields.coordinates = L.latLng([lat, lon]);
        data.push(record.fields);
      });
      setParkingLots(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => setError(error));
  console.log(error);
};

export const useParkingLot = (): Lot[] => {
  const [parkingLots, setParkingLots] = useState<Lot[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getParkingLots(setParkingLots);
  }, [parkingLots]);

  return parkingLots;
};
```

I am trying to use the hook in my `MainTabs` component here:

```
import {
  IonTabs,
  IonTabBar,
  IonTabButton,
  IonIcon,
  IonLabel,
  IonRouterOutlet,
} from "@ionic/react";
import { map, business, calendarOutline, carOutline } from "ionicons/icons";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router";
import { CampusMap, Events, Buildings, ParkingLots } from "../../pages";
import { useFakeEvent } from "../../DataProviders";
import { useBuilding } from "../../DataProviders";
import { useParkingLot } from "../../DataProviders";

export const MainTabs: React.FC = () => {
  const buildings = useBuilding();
  const parkingLots = useParkingLot();
  const [events, setEvents] = useState(useFakeEvent());
  const [showName, setShowName] = useState(true);

  const toggleName = () => {
    console.log("resetName called");
    setShowName(false);
    return setTimeout(() => {
      setShowName(true);
    });
  };

  return (
    <IonTabs>
      <IonRouterOutlet>
        <Route path="/:tab(Events)" render={() => <Events />} exact={true} />
        <Route
          path="/:tab(Map)"
          render={() => (
            <CampusMap
              buildings={buildings}
              showName={showName}
              parkingLots={parkingLots}
              events={events}
            />
          )}
          exact={true}
        />
        <Route
          path="/:tab(BuildingList)"
          render={() => <Buildings buildings={buildings} />}
          exact={true}
        />
        <Route
          path="/:tab(ParkingLotList)"
          render={() => <ParkingLots parkingLots={parkingLots} />}
          exact={true}
        />
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/Map" />} />
      </IonRouterOutlet>

      <IonTabBar slot="bottom">
        <IonTabButton tab="Map" href="/Map" onClick={toggleName}>
          <IonIcon icon={map} />
          <IonLabel>Map</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>

        <IonTabButton tab="BuildingList" href="/BuildingList">
          <IonIcon icon={business} />
          <IonLabel>Buildings</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>

        <IonTabButton tab="Events" href="/Events">
          <IonIcon icon={calendarOutline} />
          <IonLabel>Events</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>

        <IonTabButton tab="ParkingList" href="/ParkingLotList">
          <IonIcon icon={carOutline} />
          <IonLabel>Parking Lots</IonLabel>
        </IonTabButton>
      </IonTabBar>
    </IonTabs>
  );
};
```

I have checked my code against the Rules of Hook documentation and it doesn't seem like I am breaking any. I have also checked my dependencies and they all check out. So I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You're using a hook at the top-level right above `getParkingLots`. Hook calls must be in a component or in another hook.

Comment: The `const [error, setError] = useState(false);` needs to be within a functional component body or custom hook.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I making an invalid hook call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800191/why-am-i-making-an-invalid-hook-call)

Comment: Drew Reese's comment answered my question. Is there a way for me to choose his comment as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `useState` inside `getParkingLots` function because you defined `useState` outside of functional component which causes `Invalid Hook Call`. Try initializing inside like

```
const getParkingLots = (setParkingLots: (l: Lot[]) => void) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false); // here 
  get<{ records: ApiResponse[] }>(`${apiUrl}Parking%20Lots`, { apiKey })
    .then((response) => {
      ....
    })
    .catch((error) => setError(error));
  console.log(error);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The const [error, setError] = useState(false); needs to be within a functional component body or custom hook. – Drew Reese

This fixed the error.